# What do this CSS selectors do

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I'm developing some project on bootstrap, where I encountered some problem with one class.

```
.nav-pills > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
.nav-pills > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
```

can you give me some link where I can find some information about this class^/*. It gets my code messy and you know how it's hard to google with those symbols and class keywoard )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a CSS attribute selector. You can read all about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Attribute_selectors

In your case `[class^="icon-"]` matchs elements whose class attribute starts with `icon-` followed by whatever. And `[class*=" icon-"]` matches elements who have `icon-` anywhere in the `class` attribute (mind the space at the beginning).